# Hash Tag stop window.location Javascript event

Tags: javascript, click, query-string, hashtag, window.location

When  # tag comes in end of URL in address bar such as "http://example.com/pagename#" and then on a click event I want to redirect on page by using   window.location Javascript event ,Then its not work.

```
var redirectURL = window.location.href.split('?')[0];//Remove all existing query string  
redirectURL = redirectURL + "?" + newqueryStringName + "=" + newqueryStringValue;

window.location = redirectURL;
```

How I can redirect to a new page when # exists in address bar.